# Как записать ответ пользователя в переменную в Vk_api Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я делаю ркон бота для вк, и мне нужно сделать отправление кастом команд. Для этого нужно записать сообщение пользователя (В котором он напишет команду) в переменную rcon_comand. Я пытался это сделать (код ниже), но у меня не получилось. Как это можно сделать иначе?

p.s я использовал time.sleep т. к. у меня была одна мысль, но она не сработала. На time.sleep можно не обращать внимания

```
def sender3(id, text):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0, 'keyboard' : keyboard3})

if msg == '️ отправить команду':
                    sender3(id, 'Отправьте комманду сообщением (Без "/")')
                    sender3(id, 'Команда автоматически отправится в течении семи секунд!')
                    time.sleep(7)
                    sender3(id, 'Отправляем')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    rcon_command = msg
                    print(rcon_command)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, каким образом у вас в коде появляется msg. Вообще, обработка входящих сообщений происходит за счёт longpoll.

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        rcon_command = event.obj.text
        print(rcon_command)
```

Примерно так. Касательно деталей - прочитайте документацию используемой библиотеки или же самого VK. Надеюсь, что это тот ответ, который был нужен.